# Tilemill Dynamic Tile Generation

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, leaflet, tilemill

I have recently used Tilemill and I wish to implement it for dynamic tile rendering.As I've seen an CartoDB doing in cloud system,they can query & generate dynamic tile for request with UTFGrid.

Since we have no budgets available on project,we need to implement the same functionality on private server by generating tiles on the fly per requests including querying,choropleth mapping,also changing cartocss for changing default colors.So forth,we can adjust Tilemill for static maps.

Can I use Tilemill for same functionality ? 
If not,what are my options ?

Comment: Cartodb likely uses it's own opensource Tile server (https://github.com/Vizzuality/Windshaft) which can render tiles dynamically.

Comment: I am also looking for this, just curious if you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Tilemill isn't set up to do dynamic tiling, but you can make a map in Tilemill, export the Mapnik XML and use [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to dynamically tile for you.

Comment: As I read TileStache is a way to serve exported static datasource into tiles with given parameters,how exactly does it come up with dynamism ? Can you please give an example ?

Comment: You can serve a mapnik layer which takes a mapnik xml file and dynamically creates it and stashes it for you, it can also serve static files and more importantly blend and cache them.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will be a solution or some ideas on system

http://www.3liz.com/lizmap.html

Comment: More information about the link would be helpful.